# How to run multiple shell commands one after another in Windows batch script?

Tags: windows, shell, cmd.exe

I tried using `'&'` as most of similar posts suggest but this doesn't work:

```
@echo off
call variables.bat // contains port numbers and notebook address
ssh user@remote_server "jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=%port_r%" & 
ssh -N -f -L localhost:%port_l%:localhost:%port_r% user@remote_server &
start chrome %notebook_address% 
@PAUSE
```

I basically have two shell scripts that allow me to run jupyter notebook remotely and connect to it. I run them manually one after another and I want to combine them in a single script.

The first one runs jupyter notebook on remote server:

```
@echo off 
call variables.bat  // contains port numbers and notebook address
ssh user@remote_server "jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=%port_r%" 
@PAUSE
```

Second one provides port forwarding:

```
@echo off
call variables.bat
ssh -N -f -L localhost:%port_l%:localhost:%port_r% user@remote_server
@PAUSE
```

How could I combine the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Windows command-line shell is not Bash – it's Cmd.exe, sometimes called "batch".

If you want to run both commands *simultaneously*, then it would indeed be `&` in Bash, but in Cmd that doesn't have the "background" effect; it only does the exact same thing as just putting the two commands one after another in separate lines.

To run something in parallel, you can most likely use `start` here as well:

```
@echo off
call variables.bat
start ssh user@remote_server "jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=%port_r%"
start ssh -N -f -L localhost:%port_l%:localhost:%port_r% user@remote_server
start chrome %notebook_address% 
pause
```

Though regarding the two `ssh` connections, I don't see why they couldn't be combined into one (i.e. just invoking the actual command and setting up the forwarding at the same time, instead of using `-N`):

```
@echo off
call variables.bat
start ssh -f -L localhost:%port_l%:localhost:%port_r% user@remote_server "jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=%port_r%"
start chrome %notebook_address% 
pause
```

Comment: worked like a charm. Thank you!